# .NET Core Controller Run Dapper Query and write to a file in background

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Our use case requires huge processing of data extraction and writing to a file to be further processed by other processors.

Due to the fact that there is a lot of data involved, it's impossible for the the service that request to wait for a response and then pass the data to be processed by the worker processor.

Trying to achieve "fire and forget" type of mechanism here, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("request/ret")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostData([FromBody][BindRequired] modelnh request,
        [Required] string code, [FromServices]IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = new List<rbt>();

    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    qrest = (List<rbt>)await _bkgservice.GetData(request,code, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);;
                    await _filehelper.SaveToFile(qrest ,tgtdirec, append);

                }
            });

    return Ok;
}
```

BKGService:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<rbt>> GetData(rbt request, string code)
{
    string query = "SELECT * ........";
    result = await _dbprov.RunQueryAsync<rbt>(query);
    return result;
}
```

I have not included the `SaveToFile` method code, but I think the question is understood here.

Comment: What's not working? What issues are you getting?

Comment: @Orifjon , the problem I am running into is that the program is doing fire and forget , but the dapper query is not being executed (traced on the sql side) and subsequently no file is created

Comment: Any recommendation or suggestions that i can try.

Comment: It may be the problem from database not returning any data and hence its not able to write any file. Need to debug the program.

Comment: I have verified two things, one it has data and the other thing is when executed with task.run I don’t even see the connection being established in the session logs in the database

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code is defining a `scope`, but it's not actually using it. E.g., `_bkgservice` is the one injected into the controller, not a new one retrieved from the scope:

```
using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
  qrest = (List<rbt>)await _bkgservice.GetData(request,code, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);;
  await _filehelper.SaveToFile(qrest ,tgtdirec, append);
}
```

Since the code is using fire-and-forget, if `_bkgservice` and `_filehelper` are scoped services, they may be disposed before the code in the `Task.Run` actually uses them. Also, since the code is using fire-and-forget, any exceptions are ignored, so it's not obvious at all what is happening.

A quick solution is to enforce the `Task.Run` code to use services resolved from the scope, e.g., using a `static` local method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostData([FromBody][BindRequired] modelnh request,
        [Required] string code, [FromServices]IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var result = new List<rbt>();

  // Code in a static local method cannot accidentally access members.
  // When adding parameters, ensure that you do not add any values that are dependency-injected.
  static async Task DoWorkAsync()
  {
    using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
      var bkgService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TBkgService>();
      var fileHelper = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FileHelper>();
      qrest = (List<rbt>)await bkgservice.GetData(request,code, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);;
      await filehelper.SaveToFile(qrest ,tgtdirec, append);
    }
  }

  _ = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync());

  return Ok;
}
```

However, even if you get it compiling (and - for some definition of the term - "working"), you still have the problems of fire-and-forget. Specifically:

1. Fire-and-forget work may occasionally be lost, e.g., when you do rolling upgrades.
2. Fire-and-forget work silently ignores errors.

Fire-and-forget is inherently dangerous, and generally unsuitable for any real-world production application. Instead of using fire-and-forget, I recommend either:

1. Not using fire-and-forget. Just let `PostData` complete naturally *after* it has completed its work. OR:
2. Develop a proper [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as I describe on my blog.

Answer (score -3):

you can run a Dapper query and write the results to a file in the background by using asynchronous programming and background tasks. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:
Install Required NuGet Packages
Create a Dapper Query
Write Data to a File
Background Task

Comment: This is more of a summary of an answer than an actual answer. It is lacking detail and does not address any of the specific problems described in the original question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).